# Shell command grep a record from a .TAR file that holds .GZ files

Tags: shell, tar, archive

I am trying to grep a string out of specific .gz file in an archived .tar file.

The contents of that `tar` file has an archive per host, looking something like:

```
APPLOG/cp13ap011/logs/domeus.log.2021-07-09.gz
APPLOG/cp15ap043/logs/domeus.log.2021-07-09.gz
APPLOG/cp14ap411/logs/domeus.log.2021-07-09.gz
APPLOG/cp11ap231/logs/domeus.log.2021-07-09.gz
```

I located the file location
`find /backup/tmp/ -type f -name 'APPLOG-P10-2021-07-09.tar' |xargs zgrep -F 'communicationId=6700409965' >> ~/tmp/2021_07_09.txt`

When I realised its a .tar file, holding the record in the demos

`tar -tf APPLOG-P10-2021-07-09.tar -O |find APPLOG/ -type f -name 'domeus.log.2021-07-09*' | xargs zgrep -E "Id=6700409965" >> ~/tmp/2021_07_09.txt`

The file is located here `APPLOG/domeus.log.2021-07-09.gz` there are multiple machines that hold the record, but all machines would have a duplicated file name domeus.log.2021-07-09* and file is massive so it needs to refine the string `"Id=6700409965"`

The end it is not getting me a result of those files

> -rw-r--r-- 1 0 Nov 15 16:58 2021_07_09.txt

The trick , I do not want to ***unzip*** the file unless there are no other options

Comment: `tar | find` doesn't make sense. `find` doesn't read from stdin so it won't see anything `tar` is sending it.

Comment: How important is it to do this efficiently? If it's very important, I'd use a different language, like Python, where the `tarfile` module lets you do all this in a single pass. The easy ways to do it in bash involve reading your input file twice (once to get the available names, once to extract content with the specific name(s) you care about).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I'd love to do that, but I barely have access to do anything on our backup

Comment: I don't know what you mean re: not having access. Do you mean you don't have a Python interpreter available? (That would be surprising on a modern-ish system; Python has been built into most Linux distros for something like 20 years now).

Comment: ...anyhow, if you're okay with a slower approach that reads your input files twice, that's fine, we can implement that in bash easily enough.

Comment: In addition to @Charles Duffy, instruct tar to only extract the specific gz file you are after and then pipe directly to zgrep.

Comment: Also, if you don't have Python, that raises concerns about how old your version of bash is. What version are you working with?

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk, right, the question is if the OP has the full filename of that specific gz file before starting. (If they did, why would they use `find` at all?)

Comment: @Haitham, to be clear, this _might_ be as easy as `tar -xf APPLOG-P10-2021-07-09.tar -O domeus.log.2021-07-09.gz | gunzip -c >output-location`. But you haven't given enough information in the question for us to be sure. The output of `tar -tf` would be useful as a starting point.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, there are multiple machines that hold the record, but all machines would have a duplicated file name ```domeus.log.2021-07-09*```

Comment: @Haitham, please put that information inside the question itself. Ideally, with an example of the actual output from `tar -tf`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Also the file is huge, its 8GB , I just need specific string ```"Id=6700409965"```

Comment: @Haitham, ...that changes nothing substantive; then just `tar -xf file.tar -C file-to-extract | zgrep ... >output-location`.

Comment: @Haitham, ...and again, how to fill out `file-to-extract` depends on details you have persisted, thus far, in not giving us -- despite being asked multiple times.

Comment: (when you say "multiple machines" -- does each machine have a different _directory_ like `APPLOG`? Does each machine have a different tar file? We don't know what "multiple machines" means in the context of this question).

Comment: (mind, no matter what, `tar` is reading the tar file from the front until it gets to the data you're searching for -- it isn't an indexed format; having a footer that describes where to search to to find different files is one of the innovations that made `zip` special when it first came out, but `tar` is older).

Comment: I have updated the question, Ok to answer yours in specific

APPLOG/cp13ap011/logs/domeus.log.2021-07-09.gz
APPLOG/cp15ap043/logs/domeus.log.2021-07-09.gz
APPLOG/cp14ap411/logs/domeus.log.2021-07-09.gz
APPLOG/cp11ap231/logs/domeus.log.2021-07-09.gz

I would just add * after the APPLOG to get the list

Comment: I'm going to [edit] that comment into the question -- comments should only be supplemental information, but those filenames are critical for producing a correct answer.

Comment: And to repeat another question I asked you earlier: Which **specific version of bash** does this need to support? Is it an answer that works with bash 4.0 and later acceptable?

Comment: GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: One other thing. Are you using `>>` because you want to append to the file _within the same run of your script_, or do you want the script, when run multiple times, to concatenate _all_ those runs into your output file next to each other?

Comment: The ```>>``` is to get all the results into a file to be able to read after

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239249/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-haitham).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, doing this in bash is going to require multiple passes -- it would be much more efficient in Python, where the `tarfile` module lets you both decide which files you want to inspect, and read the content of those files, in one pass.

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' tarfile; do
  tar -xf "$tarfile" -T <(
    tar -tf "$tarfile" |
      grep -E 'APPLOG/(.*)/logs/domeus[.]log[.]2021-07-09[.]gz'
  ) -O |
    gunzip -c |
    grep 'Id=6700409965'
done < <(find /backup/tmp/ -type f -name 'APPLOG-P10-2021-07-09.tar' -print0) \
     >~/tmp/2021_07_09.txt
```

---

Providing documentation for the individual techniques used:

- `while read` loops are discussed in detail in [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).
- `<(...)` is [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) syntax -- it expands to a filename from which the output of `...` can be read, which is on modern platforms implemented with a named pipe or equivalent (so that content doesn't need to be written to disk and the processes can run in parallel).
- `tar -T` expects the next argument to be a list of filenames to operate on.

Comment: tar: option requires an argument -- 'C'
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `-O`, not `-C`.

Comment: @Haitham, it's been a few days, so I'm curious where you're at -- if your devops staff had a better approach, any chance it could turn up as an answer here? And have you tried rerunning after fixing the `-O`/`-C` thinko?